# Can I run cloud-based native mobile app testing from cloud?

Tags: browserstack, saucelabs, perfecto, kobiton, headspin

I wrote tests in Robot Framework with Appium. I test the same app on both Android and iOS.

I want to find out a cloud-based native mobile app testing vendor where (a) I can test the app on various mobile devices and (b) I could also run the tests in the cloud.

I am looking into perfecto, Kobiton and HeadSpin, which seem only to provide access to devices. Are there vendors that allow running tests in the cloud as well?

Comment: Try using BrowserStack's real mobile devices for your use case.

Comment: @AshwaniPathak can you please explain a little further in an answer? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: @AshwaniPathak like how do these platforms differ?

Comment: Posted. I would recommend you to schedule a demo with BrowserStack on the website. The Automate and other BrowserStack product suite is really cool.